# How to convert "127.0.0.1:8080" to www.projectname.com" on local?

Tags: django, dns

How can I change a URL on django running server from `127.0.0.1:8080` to `http://www.projectname.com`?

Comment: Have a read of this article: https://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name/

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. If you would like to serve your application from your machine to any client over the internet you need to either buy a domain or use a dynamic DNS service. This will enable domain address resolution to your IP.
2. If you want to have a domain name on your N/W for a specific client machines, for windows locate the host file on the desired client (On server or machine on the same network) and make an entry like `192.168.1.2 www.projectname.com` and run your server on port 80 for http. (change 192.168.1.2 to your server's IP address).

Editing host file on Windows:

> - Press the Windows key.
> - Type Notepad in the search field.
> - In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as    administrator.
> - From Notepad, open the following    file:c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

Editing the host file in linux:

> - Open a Terminal window.
> - Enter the following command to open the hosts file in a text editor:    sudo nano /etc/hosts.
> - Enter your domain user password.
> - Make the necessary changes to the file.
> - Press Control-X.
> - When you are asked if you want to save your changes, enter y.

You should also consider hosting the server using a apache or Ngix server with default port 80.